# Prove:If $f$ is holomorphic from $D \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C} \setminus (0,1) $, then $f$ has a removable singularity or pole at $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove:If  $f$ is holomorphic from $D \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C} \setminus (0,1) $, then $f$ has a removable singularity or pole at $0$.
For clarification:

$D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | |z| \lt 1 \} $

And the condition on $f$ is:
$f$ is holomorphic from $D \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C} $ and
$0 \lt |z| \lt 1 \implies f(z) \notin (0,1)$

So far I've tried disproving that 0 is an essential singularity but got nowhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know Picard's theorems?

Comment: We haven't learned it in class so unfortunately I can't use it.

Comment: Can you use the Riemann's mapping theorem?

Comment: I can use it. If I use it I can get a bijective holomorphic function from the disk without 0 to the disk, but how do I go further? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Actually I don't think I can use it because f's image isn't simply connected.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(z)$ is nonconstant, then by the open mapping theorem $f(z)\not\in[0,1]$ for $z\in D\backslash\{0\}$. 
Therefore $\frac{1}{f} : D\backslash\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}\backslash[1,\infty)$ is holomorphic. 
$\mathbb{C}\backslash[1,\infty)$ is open and simply connected, so by Riemann's mapping theorem there exists a biholomorphic mapping $\psi : \mathbb{C}\backslash[1,\infty) \to D$. 
Now, $\psi \circ \frac{1}{f}: D\backslash\{0\} \to D$ is holomorphic and bounded, so its singularity at $z=0$ is removable. 
It follows that $z=0$ is also a removable singularity of $\frac{1}{f}$ (why?),
so $f=\frac{1}{\varphi}$ for $\varphi\not\equiv0$ holomorphic in $D$. 
If $\varphi(0)\neq0$ then $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Otherwise,  $z=0$ is a zero of $\varphi$ of multiplicity, say, $m$, and $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z=0$.